# Do photons cast shadows

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-electrodynamics

Large objects, for instance a tree, can cast shadows. Do elementary partices such as photos cast shadows. And can this be proven?

Comment: No, because photons just pass right through each other.

Comment: Isn't this debatable since super high energy photons can crash into low energy photons?

Comment: This can happen very rarely, but I thought you were asking about things that happen in practice, i.e. a real shadow you could actually see.

Comment: Minute physics youtube.  https://youtu.be/Fv1JJ227CQk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The casting of shadows is caused by the absorption and/or reflection of light. Generally light does not absorb or reflect itself. Photon photon scattering is possible and has been detected under extreme conditions at CERN, but it is not a manifest phenomenon in everyday conditions.